# How do I select mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

> ```
>                if(!mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd)){
>                     die("Hoops, error! ".mysql_error());
>                 }
> ```

...no error from here.

```
                if(!mysql_select_db($db,$connect)){
                    $create_db = "CREATE DATABASE {$db}";
                    mysql_query($create_db,$connect);
                    mysql_query("USE DATABASE {$db}",$connect);
                }
```

..."no database selected" error from here.
I would like to select database if it exists and if doesn't then create it and select it.

Why is my code not right?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure $db is a valid database name?

Comment: yes I'm sure about it (its employers), I tried it also without variable and it still didn't work.

Comment: Whats with the braces? I haven't worked with mysql/php in ages, but I don't remember that at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you saving the value returned by mysql_connect()? Don't see it here. I assume $host, $user, $password and $db are properly set ahead of time. But you're passing a param to mysql_select_db that may not be properly set.

```
$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd);
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if(!mysql_select_db($db,$connect)) ...
```

Start by checking to see if you can select *without* the CREATE query first. Try a simple SELECT query to start. If you can connect, select the db, and execute a SELECT query, that's one step. *Then* try the CREATE query. If that doesn't work, it's almost certainly a matter of permissions.

Comment: My parameters are alright. I've got variable $connect set like you wrote here. Connection is without error, it just doesn't want to select db.I have no idea.Do you?

Comment: Can you perform a simple SELECT query on $db? Leave out the CREATE query to test. Do you get an error? If so, what mysql_errno is returned?

Answer (score 1):

You might need database create permissions for the user attempting to create the database.
Then you need to operate on a valid connection resource. $connect never looks to be assigned to the connection resource.

Comment: the same user can create database from command line. I get error "No database selected", nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the **CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS** syntax instead?

Something like this ...

```
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost');
  $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {$db}';
  if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    print("success.\n");
  } else {
    print("Database {$db} creation failed.\n");
  }
  if(!mysql_select_db($db,$connect)){
    print("Database selection failed.\n");
  }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but the return was failed and failed :(. variable $connect is ok, it doesn't return any error, so I really don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Sounds like your MySQL user doesn't have enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value of mysql_query() - currently if any of those calls fail you won't know about it:

```
if(!mysql_select_db($db,$connect)){
    if (!mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE $db", $connect)) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db($db, $connect)) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: it's so weird, it doesn't report any error. It says "no database selected" only at the point when I want to insert data into table.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
mysql_query($create_db,$connect);
mysql_query("USE DATABASE {$db}",$connect);
```

To

```
mysql_query($create_db,$connect);
mysql_select_db($db);*
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you could try w3schools website. They have a very simple and easy to learn tutorial for selecting database. The link is : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank to all of you, however I found fault on my side. This script was in class and one of variables were not defined inside this class. So I'm really sorry. 
I don't know how to consider the right answer, but I noticed my mistake after reading Clayton's answer about not properly set parameters, so I guess he is the winner ;)

Comment: @perfectDay The good thing is you got the problem solved. I was beginning to wonder what happened with this one ... Thanks.